# Проблема с проверкой рефреш токенов при обновлении страницы React. С сервером Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Есть страница авторизованного пользователя[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR32e.png)
Так же есть форма авторизации
Когда вы входите на сайте и авторизовываетесь всё работает прекрасно, но при частом обновлении страницы сервер судя по всему не успевает сравнить токен в db и токен в localstorege и создает новый в связи с чем авторизация слетает.
Как это исправить?
Я выделил где на сервере +- происходит ошибка

Мне нужно чтоб авторизация не вылетала при частом обновлении страница, или чтоб при частом нажатии обновления страница обновлялась только 1 раз.[![введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код пожалуйста в текстовом виде оформите

Comment: Посмотри вот это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN25fMQZ2v0 там довольно приемлемо показан вариант с авторизацией...

Comment: @ksa я по его примеру и сделал. Но там есть собственно эта проблема

Comment: @Duracell вам нужно все сервисы контроллеры дто и тп ?)

Comment: @БогданКабанов, мы в свое время сделали один раз - теперь просто дублируем для разных задач...

Comment: @ksa я не понял что вы имел ввиду, я говорю я сделал по этому видео ролику. Но нашёл вот этот, так скажем баг. И мне хотелось бы его решить )

Comment: @БогданКабанов, я это понял. Так же помню что мы что-то еще дописывали... Но там уже много чего добавлено и показать это уже не смогу.

Comment: @ksa всё равно спасибо